# Web API Post call from c# client always return with 200 OK

Tags: rest, c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api2

I got a C# client that performs POST call like so:

```
public void Add(ModelA newObj)
{
           HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.x.com/api/ModelA");
           string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newObj, Formatting.None,
           new  JsonSerializerSettings { 
            PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.All
            });
            var messagebyte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(json);
            httpRequest.Method = "POST";
            httpRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
            httpRequest.ContentLength = messagebyte.Length;
            // Send request
            using (var stream = httpRequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                stream.Write(messagebyte, 0, messagebyte.Length);
                stream.Close();
            }
            // Get response
            using (var response = httpRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
            {
                response.Close();
            }
}
```

And the controller looks like that:

```
[ResponseType(typeof(ModelA))]
public IHttpActionResult PostModelA(ModelA newModelA)
{
            return NotFound();
}
```

And surprisingly, the client response is 200 OK. Moreover, the property of "response.Method" is "GET" instead of "POST". What am I missing here ?

Comment: Apparently, my POST call is routed to GET. I have put the "return NotFound()" under by GET handler and I got a "not found" error.. This problem is getting very wierd

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so apparently my web host changed some configuration and the API calls should have been made to http://x.com instead of http://www.x.com.

I found it out since I tried to perform POST call using the service of https://www.hurl.it/, and the call returned something like that:

```
HEADERS

Content-Length: 163
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Mon, 29 Dec 2014 04:40:55 GMT
Location: http://x.co/api/ModelA
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-Powered-By-Plesk: PleskWin
BODY view raw

<head>
  <title>Document Moved</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Object Moved</h1>This document may be found 
  <a HREF="http://x.com/api/ModelA">here</a>
</body>
```